# how to connect db in mongodb and fetch the data from collection in perl

Tags: mongodb, perl

I have used perl 5.16 V and MongoDB 3.2.1 Version.
I use the below code but data not fetch. Is any issue in my code?

```
############################################
stored data in collection tbl_ads
> db.tbl_ads.find()
{ "_id" : "103607835" "title" : "Massief Grenen Parket Winterprijs -50","user_id" : "11", "website_id" : "1" }
##########################################################
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use MongoDB;
use Data::Dumper;


my $client = MongoDB::Connection->new;
my $db   = $client->get_database( 'temp_db' );

my $people_coll = $db->get_collection("tbl_ads");
my $ad_hash = $people_coll->find({"user_id"=>"11"});
print Dumper $ad_hash;
```

Comment: I got it for print the return hash by mongodb.my $people = $people_coll->find;
while (my $p = $people->next) {
    print Dumper $p;
}

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a lot of pieces, let me try and help you out:

```
$client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new("host" => "your-server-here:port");
$client->connect;

# Not sure if you are using auth or not, you need to specify the collection you authenticate against
$client->authenticate('user-collection', 'user', 'pass');

$database = $client -> get_database('temp_db');
$document = $database -> get_collection('tbl_ads')->find_one({"user_id"=>"11"});

print Dumper $document;
```